# How To Display Product Details When Selecting A Product using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I'm currently building a mobile app using Xamarin Forms and it's my first time doing so.

It's basically an ecommerce shopping cart where I pull the data using REST API, it shows the list of products and then the user can add to cart.

I need help in the best way to display the individual product details when a user clicks on the product within the list.

So for example, when I click on the product category, it will show a list of products.

How do I display the individual product details on another page when I select a product?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my productpage.xaml where it displays all the products correctly.

```
<ListView x:Name="productsListView"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"                       
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="20" Margin="20">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding featured_src}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="00">
                                            <Label WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding price , StringFormat='${0}'}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                        </Frame>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                        
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I just need to figure out how to display the individual products.

Comment: Create a product details page? Anyway you are not really at the point of asking a question, you have no programming problem atm, just a small research one. Please try a few things and if you have trouble then make a more detailed post with what you are trying and what is not working

Comment: like @TheGeneral says, you would generally create a 2nd page for the ProductDetail, and when they click on a product you would Navigate to that page, passing a Product ID or object, which the Detail page would use to populate its UI.   There are numerous samples available from Xamarin that you could look at for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I display the individual product details on another page when I
> select a product?

First, your app should start with a `NavigationPage`:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

You can push to another page with specific product `dataModel` to show the selected product details in `OnItemSelected` method:

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

    dataModel selectedProductModel = e.SelectedItem as dataModel;

    Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetail(selectedProductModel));
}
```

And you should have a `ProductDetail` page to show the details:

```
public partial class ProductDetail : ContentPage
{
    public ProductDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ProductDetail(dataModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //get the produce info from model and show it in this page
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jack! It's working!! :D Keep up the awesome work!